# Path of Images inside a component in Joomla

Tags: joomla, filepath

I have this very simple problem re file paths, and yet I have been
trying to solve the problem to no avail. Your help would be much appreciated.
I'm new to Joomla and here is my problem.

I would like to show an image located in the images folder of my component.

Example Path:

```
/joomlabasedir/components/com_mycomponent/images/image1.png
```

How can I correctly set the path to this image, from inside a view of my component.

I've tried the following in my code:

```
<img src="./images/images1.png">
```

But when the page gets loaded, the src gets prefixed with the SEF formatted link of the page that is currently being displayed.

Example. While viewing a 'View' called event, instead of the image path pointing to : `localhost/joomla/components/com_mycomponent/images/image1.png,`
it points to the SEF formatted link as show below,

```
localhost/joomla/index.php/component-alias/event/images/image1.png
```

which is obviously the wrong path and results to a 404 error.

I have also tried using JPATH_ROOT, JPATH_COMPONENT, and also failed since these paths are actually giving the filesystem path of the file, which is considered as local resource thus can't be loaded.

I hope someone can help me on this seemingly trivial problem that I failed solve.

Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<img src="<?php echo JURI::root();?>components/com_mycomponent/images/images1.png">
```

Comment: hi, i was able to solve this one on my own using the exact solution you gave... ehehe any thank you!

Comment: I don't see much use for this. What is exactly the benefit here? I can just use a root relative link: `/components/com_mycomponent/images/images1.png` was looking for something useful like not having to specify the component name and do something like `"<?php echo JURI::component();?>/images/images1.png"`

Comment: does the same thing, looks fine to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JCE editor (i think it's the most effective), your default directory is /images/stories.

So...you must create a directory inside the stories directory, and when you link it, just write "directoryname/image1.png" in source, or just click the image button, and your directory will show with the image inside ! Click the image, and isert!

If you don't want to copy your image there, you can link like http://yoursite.com/components/com_componentname/images/image1.png like a usual URL.

Comment: not really the kind of answer i was looking for, but thanks all the same!